# How to position a caption below a picture and with the same width?

Tags: css, position, css-position

I would like to position caption below my picture (but still on it) and its with to be the same width of the picture (the with of the pictures can change).

Here is what I have done but after hours of research I've been unable to figure out how to do extend the width of the caption to the same width of the picture. Can somebody give me a hint? Thank you

```
figure{
    position: relative;
}
figure img{
    z-index: 1;
}
figure .caption{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;

}

 <div class="img">
     <figure>
      <a href="#"><img  src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_xNTvSztbjn0/S9rYIIoIdkI/AAAAAAAAFHk/RCYU5iILKTc/s1600/0l+P1010254.jpg"/></a>
      <figcaption>
        <span class="caption">A short description</span>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7hKKV/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly adjusted your code:

```
figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
figure img{
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
figcaption {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
figcaption .caption {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

Set 100% width on the parent, Moved your styles for the `caption` on to the parent `figcaption`,moved the `padding` of the caption to the `span`, made your image 100% width to fill the container

http://jsfiddle.net/LF33A/1/

Answer (score 0):

you are really close. You need to add some `width: 100%` styling in order to achieve this

```
figure{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; /*Allows .caption to extend across image without going over*/
}
figure img{
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%; /*Image will be size to 100% if div.img*/
    height: auto; /*Prevents Skewing of image*/
}
```

**updated fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/7hKKV/12/

Comment: Thank you for you answer but the caption now goes over the right edge of the picture !